# AngularJs radio does not get binded to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the selected radio button to the scope and then to the server, but it's not passing. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label"> What product?</label>
            <div ng-repeat="type in typeProducts | orderBy:'name'">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.product_id" name="typeproduct" value="{{type.id}}"/>
                <label for="radio">{{type.name}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
$scope.createProduct = function() {
      Account.createProduct($scope.product)
        .then(function() {
          toastr.success('Product has been created');
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
          toastr.error(response.data.message, response.status);
        });
    };
```

The error is on the server side, since the DB doesn't accept null columns

Comment: What server are you talking about? If you think the fault is there, can you post the code? And what does this have to do with Angular?

Comment: I put it wrong. It appears a 500 error, but it's because one of the fields is missing when I try to create a new product. That field is the same that is not being passed to the scope. The selected radio is not being passed to the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the model to be an object with an id property like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="product.id" value="{{type.id}}" ng-/>
      <label for="radio">{{type.name}}</label>
```

You will also need to initialize $scope.product in the controller

```
$scope.product = {};
```

or if you know what the default value to select is use

```
$scope.product = {'id': 1};
```

Here is an example of this working http://codepen.io/mkl/details/xVLdjb/

Comment: It solved my problem, but what's the difference between using `ng-model="$parent.product_id"` and `ng-model="product.product_id"` or `ng-model="$product.id"`? I mean, all of them should work.

Comment: This site might help explain the difference better than I can...  http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/25/radio-buttons-with-angularjs.aspx